# Updating auto layout after changing an object's frame size

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

I am creating a view using auto layout and the result is this.

[image]

After the view loads, then I grab some text data and fill the UITextView's. The "About me" item can be multiple lines, so I resize that specific frame. Then, I get the following.

[image]

You see how the about me textview is covering the next field? How can I resize the auto layout with the new about me textview size? I searched and found some suggestions to use setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded, but none worked.

I am setting up the auto layout like the following:

```
    inputsContainerView.addSubview(ageInput)
    ageInput.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    ageInput.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    ageInput.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    ageInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    inputsContainerView.addSubview(genderInput)
    genderInput.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    genderInput.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageInput.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    genderInput.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    genderInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    inputsContainerView.addSubview(aboutInput)
    aboutInput.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    aboutInput.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderInput.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    aboutInput.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    aboutInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    inputsContainerView.addSubview(memberSinceInput)
    memberSinceInput.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    memberSinceInput.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aboutInput.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    memberSinceInput.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    memberSinceInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

After the view loads, I fetch data and resize the about me textview's frame using the following function:

```
func resizeTextView(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: You are mixing auto-layout with setting the frame directly.  You should do one of the other.  In this case instead of setting the frame directly you could store the height constraint and update its constant.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Can you give a brief example on how to do this? I tried setting the height constraint of that textview only and then called updateConstraint on the view that contains it. It doesnt seem to work. Am I doing the right way?

Comment: Well the `UITableView` answer is probably a better solution but what you can do is store the height constraint like this `heightConstraint = aboutInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)` (don't forget to activate it).  Then later on change it's constant to the new height like this `heightConstraint.constant = newHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use `UITableView` to create this form and add the label and UITextView inside the cells.

You could do a `UITableViewCell` like below where I set the height of label to 60 and auto layout it. UITextView also using the auto layout and fitting the cell's bottom.

```
import UIKit

class UserDetailCell: UITableViewCell {

    var userDetailLabel : UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return label
    }()

    var userDetailTextView : UITextView = {
        var tv = UITextView()
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.isScrollEnabled = false
        return tv
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupUI()
    }

    func setupUI(){
        addSubview(userDetailLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                userDetailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                userDetailLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8),
                userDetailLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
                userDetailLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
            ])

        addSubview(userDetailTextView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            userDetailTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userDetailLabel.bottomAnchor),
            userDetailTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            userDetailTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            userDetailTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Then your `UIViewController` should be like below. I'm setting a delegate to UITextView inside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method. Since I set the delegate, the `textViewDidChange` delegate method will be called. It is written inside an extension.

```
import UIKit

class UserDetailsController: UITableViewController {

    let cellId = "cell"
    var person = Person(myAge: 20, myGender: "Male", aboutMe: "Hello my name is jake waisee. What is your name? goayngeHello my name is jake waisee. What is your name? goayngeHello my name is jake waisee. What is your name? goayngeHello my name is jake waisee. What is your name? goaynge")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UserDetailCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 3
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserDetailCell
        cell.userDetailTextView.delegate = self
        cell.userDetailTextView.tag = indexPath.row
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.userDetailLabel.text = "Age"
            cell.userDetailTextView.text = "\(person.age)"
        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            cell.userDetailLabel.text = "Gender"
            cell.userDetailTextView.text = person.gender
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            cell.userDetailLabel.text = "About me"
            cell.userDetailTextView.text = person.aboutMe
        }

        return cell
    }

}


extension UserDetailsController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
        if textView.tag == 2 {
            person.aboutMe = textView.text
        }else if textView.tag == 0 {
            person.age = Int(textView.text) ?? 0
        }else if textView.tag == 1 {
            person.gender = textView.text
        }

        //this will keep the textview growing as we type
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Your UI should look something like below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will give this a try!

Comment: I tried it and it worked! 
Now I modified the code so that the tableView.dataSource is set to an external Model called ProfileViewModel. The UITableViewDataSource is defined in the ProfileViewModel and in its cellForRowAt function, I can't do `cell.userDetailTextView.delegate = self` because the self here will be ProfileViewModel. Is it possible to set the delegate that is defined in UserDetailsController?